# Find out what is hammering my HDD periodically as its occurring

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

Occasionally, my Windows 7 PC HDD activity is getting absolutely hammered (like right now). And this lasts for a number of hours. It makes everything really 'laggy' and 'sluggish' effecting productivity immensely.

- You can hear the HDD activity where it is constantly struggling to do something during this period.
- The HDD light is on constantly during this period.

Is there any way I can find out exactly what it is doing so I can prevent whatever task it is from running?

Task manager doesn't shed any light in terms of what programs and processes are running. The CPU usage under the performance tab is quite indicative of the PC being hammered.

This is just becoming really frustrating - it's as if there is some sort of PC scan happening behind the scenes somewhere.

Comment: You say that "Task manager doesn't shed any light in terms of what programs and processes are running" but still "CPU usage under the performance tab is quite indicative of the PC being hammered". What do you mean with this? CPU usage is high but no process seems to consume CPU? In that case it might be a system process (BTW, turn on *Show processes from all users* in the Processes tab to see processes other than your own).

Comment: I mean that I am aware of all that is running and these aren't the cause. Something specifically is being activated without my knowledge and causing a large load on HDD. I think your answer will pinpoint the cause though. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find out what process is causing much disk I/O by firing up *Resource Monitor* (from Task Manager on the Performance tab click on Resource Monitor... button). There go to *Disk* tab and find the processes(es) from *Disk Activity* view that top in the *Total* column.

For additional details on the Resource Monitor regarding disk activity there's a good looking article in [Tech Republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/use-resource-monitor-to-monitor-storage-performance/4233).

Comment: Brilliant, this is what I was after, I will monitor this next time the  issue occurs to identify exactly what it is. Thanks.

Comment: If you do fail identifying the process with this approach it's worth looking into the answer Dave Rook gave.

Comment: It's just started happening again. I'm not entirely sure how to use this Resource Monitor but the 'System' has gone crazy and it looks like it has something to do with 'pagefile.sys'... HDD goes nuts while this process has stupendous figures and then it just suddenly disappears and HDD calms down.

Comment: Is your system low on memory? Lot of activity with page file (*swapping* for short) means the system is using virtual memory when the physical RAM is exhausted. I've also seen this happen when closing up an large application which has been earlier pushed to virtual memory due to having been idle.

Comment: This machine has got 8Gb RAM and 'Memory' under 'Performance' in Task Manager is quite often at 75% + used. The issue is definitely between 'System' 'pagefile.sys' and 'NTFS Volume Log' [link](http://windows7themes.net/what-is-ntfs-volume-log-logfile-and-why-is-it-causing-disk-activity-in-windows-7.html). These processes are absolutely maxxing out the system which is the cause. I'm just not sure why still.

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons but sometimes it's due to a faulty hard drive

Use a SMART tool to check the condition of the hard drive.

Use a program like Process Monitor to see what is going on (some configuration may be required).

You could consider starting the machine in safe mode, or removing all start up programs via MSCONFIG to see if the issue continues (thus finding what program it is).

You may want to (if safe to do so) disable your AV to see if it is a scan

Also confirm if the issue occurs when you're not connected to a network.

Also make sure your machine is clean (virus/malware free).

Comment: Process Monitor is a great recommendation and will surely help in these cases. Possible culprits other than AV-software could also be a scheduled defrag, Windows Search Indexer and Superfetch. Of course there could also be malware searching through the system, but in this case it will be easily identified with ProcMon.

Comment: Process Monitor was useless as it couldn't even stay open while my HDD was getting hammered. Error: 'a system or application resource limit has been exceeded that prevents process monitor from capturing additional events'.

Comment: I am going to give the following a go though: `chkdsk /b /v /x C:` on boot... This has appeared to resolve astronomically high disk activity when practically idle for other Windows users.

Comment: @Geoff ProcMon allows two capture modes: capturing to memory and to HDD. You should avoid capturing to HDD for obvious reasons and also make sure to have at least 1GB of free memory (more the longer you capture and the more processes are going on)

Comment: I see, thanks for the details - I shall check it out again soon.